# Working locally on web-application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I have been added as developer on application.

On Applications Overview this app is shown together with my other app, that I can freely access and change via Google App Engine Launcher.

Question is how to get app I'm supposed to work on my computer locally(in other words in GAE), so I can test and change it locally in the browser on my computer...

Windows 7

App Engine SDK-release: "1.7.6"

API: python27

Comment: Pulling the app code from GAE is probably not the right approach. Hopefully whoever is already working on it is doing so under some form of version control and you should obtain the code via the appropriate SCM client.

Comment: Ask whoever added you as a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the appcfg application (the one that handle uploads) to [download the source code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code).

This only works if the administrator has not disabled it.

However, it would be better to ask the developpers to provide you with the original source code !